# Excel VBA Getting a multiple selection from a listbox

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I have a listbox which I set to selectmulti

I am trying to get the values of the selected items with this :

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim lItem As Long
Dim nboc As Integer
Dim c As Integer

Range("G:G").Clear
nboc = Worksheets("BDD").Range("IQ2").Value
c = 0
    For lItem = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
         If ListBox2.Selected(lItem) = True Then
            c = c + 1
            Worksheets("Bordereau Prep").Range("G15:G" & 14 + c) = ListBox2.List(lItem)
            ListBox2.Selected(lItem) = False

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This works as long as I have one item selected. If I have x items selected, it returns x times the first item.

Can you help me?
(I am fairly new to VBA and am trying to learn on my own)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this line:

```
Worksheets("Bordereau Prep").Range("G15:G" & 14 + c) = ListBox2.List(lItem)
```

you override the values previously printed by this function.

In first iteration you print the value in each cell of range G15:G15 (a single cell in this case), in second iteration you print the value in each cell of range G15:G16 (so you override the value printed in first iteration) and so on.

You need to change this line like below:

```
Worksheets("Bordereau Prep").Range("G14").Offset(c, 0) = ListBox2.List(lItem)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the line:

`Worksheets("Bordereau Prep").Range("G15:G" & 14 + c) = ListBox2.List(lItem)`

It simply assigns the whole range to the last found value. Here is something that works for you, you may use it somehow further and change it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub btn()

Dim lItem   As Long
Dim c       As Long

Range("G:G").Clear

For lItem = 0 To Worksheets("Bordereau Prep").ListBox2.ListCount - 1
    If Worksheets("Bordereau Prep").ListBox2.Selected(lItem) = True Then
        c = c + 1
        Worksheets("BDD").Cells(15 + c, 7) = Worksheets("Bordereau Prep").ListBox2.List(lItem)
        'Worksheets("Bordereau Prep").Range("G15:G" & 14 + c) = Worksheets("Bordereau Prep").ListBox2.List(lItem)
        Worksheets("Bordereau Prep").ListBox2.Selected(lItem) = False
    End If
Next lItem

End Sub
```

Last but not least, you try not to use Integers in VBA, but longs. Enjoy it!